# How to save files dynamically in xamarin forms

Tags: json, xamarin.forms, dependencies

I want to save files dynamically in xamarin forms and convert the data contains in that file to json object in a button click .How Can I do this

here is my code to crate a file and write contents to that file

```
  public void CreateFile(LayerClass _data)
    {
        string _fileName = _path + _data.FileName;

        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(_fileName))
            {
                File.Create(_fileName);

                DownLoadData(_data);

                WriteLayer();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString());
        }

    }

    public async void DownLoadData(LayerClass _data)
    {
        await App.DataManager.RunAsync(_data.URL);
    }

    public void WriteLayer()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(App._response))
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine(_path, _file), false))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(App._response);
                    sw.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

when am clicking the button I want to execute these code

```
DependencyService.Get<IHelpers>().ConvertObj(_temp.FileName);


 async Task LoadData(string file)
    {
        GeoJSONData JsonData;
        try
        {
            Assembly _assembly = typeof(Helpers).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

            Stream _stream = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(file);

            if (_stream != null)
            {
                using (StreamReader _reader = new StreamReader(_stream))
                {
                    var _json = _reader.ReadToEnd();

                    JsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeoJSONData>(_json);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string _msg = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    public void ConvertObj(string file)
    {
        string _fullName = _path + file;
        if(File.Exists(_fullName))
        {
            LoadData(_fullName);
        }
    }
```

but i got null value in _stream.How can I do this.

Comment: Can you explain your scenario in a bit more depth? Also, what do you mean by dynamically?

Comment: @AnubhavRanjan The no.of files is not fixed so I want to create files each time a new file comes from the APi

Comment: Probably you can generate a GUID every time you try to save the file and store the file name in SQLite table or in AppSettings. Still, I do not have any idea from your scenario, as to what API or type of data coming in.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YouObj);

        /*
        optionel : you can use formatting and settings if you wish 
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter
        {
            DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" //for example 
        });
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YouObj, Formatting.Indented, settings);
        */


        var fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "test.json");

        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                using (File.Create(fileName)) { }
            }

            using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
            {
                var data = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(json);
                fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //TODO: exception
        }
```